# PHP/Laravel - find and read 'key-value pair' from file

Tags: php, laravel, key-value, file-read

I want to store some text informations but I don't want to use database for this. For example there is a file:

```
key1: some text information 1
key2: some text information 2
key3: another text information
```

I was wondering, what is the shortest way to find one specific value form this file using PHP or Laravel?

I could use `foreach(file('yourfile.txt') as $line) {}` loop to store text lines into array and then find the line with specific key, but maybe there is shorter or nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all lines are in the same format (`[key]: [value]`) you can simply use `explode(": ", $line)` to get the values, and then rewrite them to a PHP array;

```
// getData('yourfile.txt') returns an associative array
function getData($file) {
    $data = file($file);
    $returnArray = array()
    foreach($data as $line) {
        $explode = explode(": ", $line);
        $returnArray[$explode[0]] = $explode[1];
    }

    return $returnArray;
}
```

Comment: Little mistake there. It should be `$returnArray[$explode[0]] = $explode[1];`

Comment: And also `foreach($data as $line)`

Comment: and a ; missing after $returnArray=array()

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use array instead text file

Create a new file in the app/config directory. Let's call it constants.php

In there you have to return an array of config values.

```
return [
    'myData' => [
        'key1' => 'www.domain.es',
        'key2' => 'www.domain.us'
        // etc
    ]
];
```

And you can access them as follows

```
Config::get('constants.myData');
// or if you want a specific one
Config::get('constants.myData.key1');
```

And you can set them as well

```
Config::set('myData.key1', 'test 123');
```

Comment: Tomas wants to use a text file instead of a database for information, having to define all the values yourself is probably not what he's looking for

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to put value informations from HTML form inputs into that file. But if there is an option to set values by Config::set('myData.key1', 'test 123'); then this could be the most suitable solution for me

Comment: Tomas want to store text informations and later Tomas mention about file but for storing information you not necessarily need text file.

Comment: okay. I think Now Tomas has clarified but I still suggest you create empty key value pair first than store(set) value from HTML form as suggested in my reply(using set method).

Comment: Kamelsh.bar I dont understand. What you mean by 'create empty key value pair first'?

Comment: you can put null value for 'key1' => '', 'key2' => '', etc depending on form fields( as key1,key2,key3 ) you have than assign value when form is submitted

Comment: Ok thanks, btw what does Config::set('myData.key1', 'test 123'); do? There are hardcoded values in the file. Can this command rewrite and save hardcoded values?

Comment: hard-coded values are just to show you can make them dynamic best on fields you have in HTML form (as key) and post data as values. Config::set('myData.email', Input::get('email'));

Comment: Good job great help +1

Comment: You may want to denote that you need `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;` in order to use this, as well as set read/write permissions on the file for the given web process user account.

Comment: but the array notation is ugly, it's much cleaner to write it like `key=value`

Comment: @kamlesh.bar I can not update a value using Set in Laravel 8, can you please assist?

Comment: @ishanshah you can do something like this in Laravel 8 
config('myData.key1', 'value 1'); and to get value $value = config('myData.key1');

Answer (score 0):

@leuans answer was the basis for the following function which works better for me since it also strips newlines and makes the separator configurable.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/27917087/1497139
// getConfig('yourfile.txt','separator') returns an associative array
// example: getConfig('config.ini',': ')
function getConfig($file,$separator) {
    $data = file($file);
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach($data as $line) {
        $parts=explode($separator, $line);
        $name=trim($parts[0]);
        $value=trim($parts[1]);
        $returnArray[$name] = $value;
    }
    return $returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@leuans answer is nice but this slight modification is better by:

- allowing to be have the separator character inside the value
- trimming whitespace
- ignoring blank lines

```
    function getData($file, $separator=":") {
        $data = file($file);
        $returnArray = array();
        foreach($data as $line) {
            $line = trim($line);
            $spos = mb_strpos($line, $separator);
            if($spos !== false){
                $key = trim(mb_substr($line, 0, $spos));
                $value = trim(mb_substr($line, $spos+mb_strlen($separator)));
                $returnArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    
        return $returnArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [parse_ini_file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

It reads a file of name/value pairs into an array so they can be easily accessed, e.g:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file("data.ini");
$value = $ini['key1'];
```

data.ini can look like this:

```
; This is a comment
key1=value1
```