# What is the best way to store website settings in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, configuration, laravel-8

I need to know what is the best way to store website settings (global configuration) as per performance and security wise?

I want to store the following kind of data:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Setting1 | Value1 |
| Setting2 | Value2 |

I'm thinking about 2 ways.

1. DB (This is somewhat hard to manage, because of the key-value pairs)
2. Config file

Please advise, thanks in advance!

Comment: You might wanna take a look at Spatie's [laravel-settings](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-settings) package.

Comment: @Dan I want to achieve it without any package if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If an app must be configurable by the end user, it’s better to hold the configuration on the database. But otherwise my advice is to go with a config file.

Comment: Ok, the admin will access those variables. It will be mostly app_name, app_logo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it depends on what Settings you want to save.

1. If you want to save settings like e.g. "keep me logged in" or "notify
   me when x happens" these are settings you can store in the database.
   it is possible to make a table for all the settings, a table for the
   users and make a pivot table inbetween to store user+setting+input.
2. If you want to give the user the opportunity to set a light/dark
   mode thats stuff you can do with css/scss
3. If you want to store settings for the whole application which
   affects all users i would recommend writing that into a config.

Comment: Ok, the admin will access those variables. It will be mostly app_name, app_logo, etc.

Comment: I tried to do the third step with this method but it doesn't work when I try to set a config key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27917158/7602937

Comment: you can put these into the .env file and read from them

Comment: alternatively you can store these in the database aswell, or have a look at spatie :)